# python web scraping internet site

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

hi i am trying to scrape this internet site [Here](https://www.quantalys.com/Fonds/Composition/90649)

I would like to webscrape this table in the site:
[image]

I did this code but get an error message which is:
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'`

Any help will be helpful.
Thx

```
url = "https://www.quantalys.com/Fonds/Composition/90649"

soup = BeautifulSoup(url, "html.parser")
table = soup.find('#table10', attrs={'class':'tab-pane fade'})
table_rows = table.find_all('tr')

res = []
for tr in table_rows:
    td = tr.find_all('td')
    row = [tr.text.strip() for tr in td if tr.text.strip()]
    if row:
        res.append(row)


df = pd.DataFrame(res)
print(df)
```

Comment: If the website uses JavaScript to modify the DOM, you need something like Selenium.

Comment: but in the inspection of the site, I can see the data that I need ????

Comment: This shows the current DOM, possibly modified by JavaScript. Usually a browser has a function named "view page source" or similar to see the initial HTML page code.

Answer (score 2):

You can search through the HTTP requests being made to find out where the data is really coming from.

Here, I've chosen a string at random that appears in the section you've outlined: "Portugal".

> [image]

It gives us the corresponding request which we can inspect.

One option is to copy the request, "fetch" gives us Javascript code which can be easily converted into Python.

> [image]

```js
fetch("https://www.quantalys.com/Fonds/GetCompoTableAndGraph", {
  "headers": {
    "accept": "*/*",
    "accept-language": "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8",
    "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
    "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
    "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
    "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
    "sec-fetch-site": "same-origin",
    "x-requested-with": "XMLHttpRequest"
  },
  "referrer": "https://www.quantalys.com/Fonds/Composition/90649",
  "referrerPolicy": "strict-origin-when-cross-origin",
  "body": "ID_Produit=90649&typeCompo=1",
  "method": "POST",
  "mode": "cors",
  "credentials": "include"
});
```

In this particular case, you only need the post data:

```py
import requests

r = requests.post(
   url = 'https://www.quantalys.com/Fonds/GetCompoTableAndGraph',
   data = dict(ID_Produit='90649', typeCompo='1')
)
```

The HTML is available via `r.json()['view']` which you can load into beautifulsoup.

e.g. extracting the `Grandes Cap` values from the *"Décomposition moyenne par capitalisation"* table:

```py
>>> r = requests.post(
...    url = 'https://www.quantalys.com/Fonds/GetCompoTableAndGraph',
...    data = dict(ID_Produit='90649', typeCompo='3')
... )
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(r.json()['view'])
>>> for tag in soup.find_all(string=re.compile('Grandes Cap')):
...     tag.find_next()
<td align="right">70,9% </td>
<td align="right">86,8% </td>
<td align="right">88,9% </td>
<td align="right">89,05 % </td>
```

Or pass directly to `pd.read_html()`

```py
>>> pd.read_html(r.json()['view'])
[  Classe d'actifs Classe d'actifs.1   0  40  80
 0     Grandes Cap             70,9% NaN NaN NaN
 1     Petites Cap             18,7% NaN NaN NaN
 2       Monétaire             10,4% NaN NaN NaN,
   Classe d'actifs Classe d'actifs.1   0  45  90
 0     Grandes Cap             86,8% NaN NaN NaN
 1     Petites Cap             13,2% NaN NaN NaN
 2       Monétaire                 - NaN NaN NaN,
   Classe d'actifs Classe d'actifs.1   0  45  90
 0     Grandes Cap             88,9% NaN NaN NaN
 1     Petites Cap              7,0% NaN NaN NaN
 2       Monétaire              4,1% NaN NaN NaN,
   Classe d'actifs Classe d'actifs.1   0  45  90
 0     Grandes Cap           89,05 % NaN NaN NaN
 1     Petites Cap            7,90 % NaN NaN NaN
 2          Autres            3,05 % NaN NaN NaN]
```

Comment: It is on the date 1/07/2023 and it is different from what I want (for example in the table I want to scrape Act. Allemande is 17.2% where as it is 16.48 on 1/07/2023 where you find the data)

Comment: I only showed the first "row" as an example (note the `[0]`).

Comment: yes I know but it seems that is not the same data. There is an update in the table I want to scrape. For example, the table "Décomposition moyenne par capitalisation" has value of 70,9% for grandes cap where as if I follow the same way you mention and get combo=3, I have a value of 86.78

Comment: Ah, I see. `86.78` is the default `3 ans` value but you want the `1 an` value. `70.9` doesn't appear to come from anywhere, so they must be calculating it with some arithmetic from the `86.78` value.

Comment: It looks like they are present in the html in `r.json()['view']` - you can parse that using beautifulsoup.

Comment: it seems that `r.json()['view']`is where my data is. How can I get them in a dataframe (one for 1 an/3 ans/5 ans) which is the 3 table that I can see (even 4 but I don't know what is the 4th)

Comment: You can pass the html directly to pandas: `pd.read_html(r.json()['view'])`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the fix. But the message you get is due to table variable being `None`. So the call `soup.find('#table10', attrs={'class':'tab-pane fade'})` returns `None` instead of what you are looking for because you are calling it wrong or there is no match.

Another possibility is that variable `tr` inside `for tr in table_rows` is `None` at some point. To be sure just print both of the variables and see which one is the problematic.

Comment: so I made a mistake in soup.find('#table10', attrs={'class':'tab-pane fade'}). But what should it be ?

Comment: soup.find('div', attrs={"class": "tab-pane fade", "id": "table10"})

Comment: same error message !

Comment: Well the data is not present on the website immeadiately. Its loaded later on. I am afraid there is no simple solution to this. You will have to use different modules to help you with that. As someone above already stated. You will have to use selenium or directly call the api that loads the data yourself.

Comment: call the api that loads the data yourself ? what do you mean ?

Comment: As others have posted, you have to call "https://www.quantalys.com/Fonds/GetCompoTableAndGrap" using requests module.

Answer (score 0):

You can use requests:

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests


def get_data() -> pd.DataFrame:
    post_url = "https://www.quantalys.com/Fonds/GetCompoTableAndGraph?ID_Produit=90649&typeCompo=1"

    with requests.Session() as request:
        response = request.post(url=post_url)
    if response.status_code != 200:
        print(response.raise_for_status())

    data = response.json()

    return (pd
            .json_normalize(data=data["graph"], record_path="dataProvider")
            .drop(columns=["x"])
            ).tail(1).transpose().reset_index(names="Classe d'actifs").rename(columns={24: "Val"}).round({"Val": 1})


df = get_data()
print(df)
```

Output:

```
         Classe d'actifs  Val
0        Act. Allemagne   17.2
1             Monétaire   NaN
2         Act. Autriche   0.0
3         Act. Belgique   0.0
4    Act. Emerg. Europe   0.0
5          Act. Espagne   0.0
6   Act. Europe du Nord   24.4
7           Act. France   22.9
8            Act. Grèce   1.1
9          Act. Irlande   0.0
10          Act. Italie   0.0
11        Act. Pays-Bas   16.4
12        Act. Portugal   0.0
13     Act. Royaume-Uni   0.0
14          Act. Suisse   18.0
```