# how to webscrape an internet site to have dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i would like to webscrape the data in this [internet site](https://www.quantalys.com/Fonds/Composition/90649).
I would like to get the data:[image: here].

I have done this. I can see that there is the data that I would like (1 an/ 3 ans / 5 ans) analysis.

I don't know how to get them in a pandas dataframe ???

Any help will be helpful.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.post(url = "https://www.quantalys.com/Fonds/GetCompoTableAndGraph",
                  data = dict(ID_Produit='90649', typeCompo='1') #typeCompo = 1, 2, 3 or 6
                  )

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.json()['view'])
```

Comment: Don't duplicate questions. Edit the previous one, to which, by the way, you already got an answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76987899/6106791

Comment: it's not precisely the same question but thx I will edit the previous question

Answer (score 0):

There exists `pandas.read_html`. Which should work for this case as the html markup is done with `<Table>...</Table>`.

Link to the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html

It is a bit tedious to work with...

"Expect to do some cleanup after you call this function"
-- pandas documentation.

... but i've used it previously for a similar case. Take you time exploring the output of just calling it on the website and then carefully decide on the postporcessing.

Comment: I tried to do `
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.json()['view'])
df = pd.read_html(soup)` but get an error message `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`